# How to specify map topic for ros navigation static_layer (global costmap)?

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-melodic, global-costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have a /map topic where I have my initial map launched by map_server. But I want to change the topic for the map to /filtered_map. I want to do it because I make some restrictions on the map and publish a new map to another topic.

How can I change the map topic for navigation stack (global costmap)?

Thank you in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/352848/how-to-specify-map-topic-for-ros-navigation-static_layer-(global-costmap)?/) by [Yehor](https://answers.ros.org/users/40388/yehor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 166 on 2020-05-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you have specified your costmap layers using the hydro+ API, you can set the `map_topic` parameter under the `static_map` plugin namespace in your navigation configuration files. See the [staticmap](http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d/hydro/staticmap) page for more information.

You can learn more about the hydro version of the costmap_2d stack [here](http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d/hydro)

This would often get placed in the `costmap_common_parameters.yaml` file in a hydro setup.  You can see an example of that [here](https://github.com/utexas-bwi/segbot/blob/feature/social_navigation_layer/segbot_navigation/config/segbotv2/costmap_common_params.yaml) on a branch I have worked on.

Note that in the above case, you would add the following lines to the `costmap_common_params.yaml` file:

```
static_layer:
    map_topic: /map_filtered
```

because the staticmap plugin was specified to be in the `static_layer` namespace in the [global_costmap_params.yaml](https://github.com/utexas-bwi/segbot/blob/feature/social_navigation_layer/segbot_navigation/config/segbotv2/global_costmap_params.yaml) file on the same branch.

---

Originally posted by [maxsvetlik](https://answers.ros.org/users/28419/maxsvetlik/) with karma: 161 on 2020-05-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Yehor](https://answers.ros.org/users/40388/yehor/) on 2020-05-21**:
@maxsvetlik Thank you